# Understanding this embedded c code

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to understand this embedded c code. I think it means it is connecting port bits to some register in a bus. Correct me if I'm wrong. And what ever changes we make to the ports will be reflected on the bus registers. Here is the snippet of the code. Thanks.

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Local Variables
--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Port bits assigned to Amba Peripheral Bus (APB)
// P0^7..P0^0               // output=reg_addr, input=data_in (APB prdata)
sbit APB_SEL = P1^7;        // select a bus transaction
sbit APB_EN  = P1^6;        // enable/activate a component 0 = disable, 1 = enable
```

Comment: The code you posted is highly macro'ified / typedef'd, and it's pretty much impossible to tell from the small fragment you posted. I suggest you look for the definitions of `sbit` and `P1` to give you some clues.

Comment: @Dave - apparently it's worse than you (or I) thought (see Praetorian's answer below).  Apparently the "sbit" and "^" are compiler-specific extensions (no, that ^ isn't an XOR operator...)  Ugh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is defining bit positions to be read from registers. `sbit` defines a bit within a special function register (SFR).

```
sbit APB_SEL = P1^7;
```

Here `P1` is a previously defined SFR. The line defines APB_SEL as bit 7 (zero-based numbering) of `P1`.

[This](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_sbit.htm) link has additional details on the syntax.

Comment: +1 for the URL.  It isn't completely clear to me how an xor operation does that, but that is less relevant than that it is what seems to be the documented behaviour.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I don't think that is an XOR operation, it looks like some hokey syntax invented just for this purpose.

Comment: C that is only understood by the 8051 (or its variants) compiler :-) Embedded compilers make up such keywords and syntax all the time. For instance, the TI compiler I use at work includes keywords such as `cregister` and `interrupt`.

Comment: Thank you very much Praetorian. Your reply was really helpful! :)

Comment: @Praetorian: You are probably right about it being special syntax for that particular compiler. It's a different world, it seems.  I have to work across platforms; clearly, code using that notation more or less cannot work across platforms. (It wouldn't work as described on the compilers I work with on the machines I work on). Something like that could be carefully put into a ghetto for the machine-specific parts of some program, but we seldom get quite that close to the hardware. Other people probably do it frequently; the world is a big place, but this was eye-opening, even so.

Comment: I often feel like most people who write embedded compilers are in need of a firm attitude correction with a large, blunt object. I mean, why follow ISO- and industry standard C, when you can invite your own language syntax! The one who can come up with the most irrational argument for such syntax wins a grand price!

Comment: There are good and bad ways of extending the language.  This is one of the worst I have ever seen, since the left hand expression is indistinguishable from an XOR expression.  What compiler is this? Reference to AMBA bus suggests an ARM target, but I have never seen this before.

Comment: @Praetorian: An AMBA bus on an 8051 - seems unlikely.  More likley that this is Keil's obsolete CARM compiler from before they were bought by ARM and switched to RealView.  It seems to me that @Vikyboss may want to consider updating toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

The sbit type defines a bit within a special function register (SFR). It is used in one of the following ways:

```
sbit name = sfr-name ^ bit-position;
sbit name = sfr-address ^ bit-position;
sbit name = sbit-address;
```

Where

***name*** is the name of the SFR bit.

***sfr-name*** is the name of a previously-defined SFR.

***bit-position*** is the position of the bit within the SFR.

***sfr-address*** is the address of an SFR.

***sbit-address*** is the address of the SFR bit.

With typical 8051 applications, it is often necessary to access individual bits within an SFR. The sbit type provides access to bit-addressable SFRs and other bit-addressable objects.
For example:

***sbit EA = 0xAF;***

This declaration defines EA as the SFR bit at address 0xAF. On the 8051, this is the enable all bit in the interrupt enable register.